# how to use #ifdef inside a macro?'#' is not followed by a macro parameter

Tags: c, macros

I take a project which written in c, and there are lots of Macros.

I want to use a new macro to check if the macro is activated or not.

But the symbol `#` is reserved in macro. How to fix my code? Thanks :)

```c
#define CHECK_MACRO( macro )\
#ifdef macro
printf("defined "#macro"\n");\
#else
printf("not defined "#macro"\n");\
#endif
```

Comment: You can't do exactly what you're asking for with the preprocessor.

Comment: The C preprocessor is fairly limited.  It won't do what you're trying to get it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use preprocessor conditional directives inside a macro.  Generally speaking, the solution is to turn that inside out: use conditional directives to define the macro differently in different cases.  That will not work for a generic macro-test macro such as you propose, however, and it also is limited by the fact that it determines whether the condition holds at the point where the macro is defined, not the point where it is used.

You may perhaps take consolation in the fact that this was never going to work anyway, as a result of the fact the arguments to a function-like macro are expanded before being substituted into the macro's replacement text (except in a couple of special cases that don't apply to the key part of your code).

There are alternatives that could work if the possible values of all macros of interest are limited to short lists of tokens that may appear as or in identifiers.  There different alternatives that might be adequate if you can choose a small subset of macros that you're interested in testing.  There are no alternatives that do what you propose in its full generality, unless you count writing the conditional compilation directives directly, without a macro, which in fact is the usual way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Side note - m4 preprocssor - history/legacy.

In the early days of Unix, the 'm4' processor was used for code generation. It has enhanced features of cpp (or may be cpp is a scaled down version of m4). Specially, it has better support for multi-line macros. It continue to be used in various packages.

Worth mentioning that adding a code generation to your code will make it more complex to maintain/debug.

For example: a.m4

```
define(`CHECK_MACRO', `
#ifdef $1
printf ("defined #$1\n") ;
#else
printf ("undef #$1\n") ;
#endif
')

#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
  CHECK_MACRO(FOO) ;
  CHECK_MACRO(BAR) ;
}
```

Then build/run

```
m4 a.m4 > a.c
cc a.c
./a.out
  undef #FOO
  undef #BAR

cc a.c -DFOO
./a.out
  defined #FOO
  undef #BAR
```

Usually, the generation was integrated into Makefile with a rule 
`%.c: %.m4:
    m4 -s $< > $@`
 The -s help track source code line number (it will compile error line number matching the a.m4 source file.